# rtrim() para remover "<br>" remove também a letra "r" se for a última letra na string

Tags: php, string

Se uma string terminar com uma tag HTML, por exemplo `<br>` ou `<hr>`, ao fazer uso da função de PHP [rtrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) para limpar a referida tag, nos casos onde a letra imediatamente antes é um "r", o mesmo é removido em conjunto com a tag de HTML:

#### Exemplo

```
$string = "bubu foi almoçar<br>";
echo rtrim($string, "<br>") . PHP_EOL;

$string = "bubu foi almoçar<hr>";    
echo rtrim($string, "<hr>") . PHP_EOL;

$string = "bubu foi almoçar!";
echo rtrim($string, "!") . PHP_EOL;

$string = "bubu foi almoçar";
echo rtrim($string, "<br>") . PHP_EOL;
```

#### Resultado:

> bubu foi almoça
>   bubu foi almoça
>   bubu foi almoçar    *(correcto)*
>   bubu foi almoça

## Pergunta

Como contornar esta questão de forma a que no caso prático em que a condição em cima se verifica, o resultado não venha diferente do esperado?

[Exemplo no Ideone](http://ideone.com/EF60Mg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Isto ocorre com `trim`, `ltrim` também.

A saída está correta nos 4 casos. O problema é o uso inadequado do segundo parâmetro do `rtrim`:

Quando você diz `rtrim( $string, "<hr>" )`, está dizendo "remova do final da string todas as ocorrências dos caracteres `<`, `h`, `r` e `>`, e deixe o resto."

Note que o `r` está na lista, portanto será removido como solicitado.

Ainda, se quiser uma faixa de caracteres, pode usar o `..`.

Exemplo: `a..z` para remover letras minúsculas.

Manual: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php

### Alternativa para substrings:

Para remover qualquer outra sequência de caracteres do final, substitua-a assim:

```
$string = '<hr>teste<hr><hr>';

while( substr( $string, -4) == '<hr>' ) {
   $string = substr( $string, 0, -4 );
}

echo $string;
```

Saída:

```
<hr>teste
```

> Este foi apenas um exemplo simples como ponto de partida. Usando *arrays* dá pra fazer uma função que remove vários grupos diferentes de strings de uma vez.

Há até um exemplo nos [comentários do site do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php#49079) que faz coisa do tipo, mas que pode ser bem simplificado no meu ver.

Comment: +1 por explicar o porque de acontecer

Answer (score 8):

Você está incluindo 4 itens para exclusão no final da sua string: <,h,r e >.

Por que não fazer uso do bom e velho regex?

```
<?= preg_replace('/<hr( \/)?>$/i', '', $string); ?>
```

Isso irá substituir `<hr>` ou `<hr />` do final da string por nada.

> **Obs.**: Evite o uso de aspas duplas, pois o php irá processar o conteúdo. Ao invés disso, é preferível o uso de aspas simples, a menos
>   que você queira que o conteúdo seja processado. **Ex.**: `<?= "Meu nome é $nome"; ?>`

Abraços!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode num *laço/loop* verificar a posição dos caracteres a remover da string através do uso de [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) e *"cortar"* a string com a função [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php).

Você pode implementar isto do seguinte modo:

```
function rtrim2($str, $charlist=null) 
{ 
    $str      = (string)$str; 
    $charlist = (string)$charlist;    

    if(empty($charlist)) 
       return rtrim($str); 

    $len = strlen($charlist); 
    $offset = strlen($str) - $len; 
    while($offset > 0 && $offset == strpos($str, $charlist, $offset)) 
    { 
        $str = substr($str, 0, $offset); 
        $offset = strlen($str) - $len; 
    } 

    return rtrim($str);    
}
```

### [**Exemplo no IdeOne**](http://ideone.com/fgHJma)

Answer (score -4):

Tenta usar `str_replace("<br>", "". $palavra);`

Comment: Olá, Alisson. Sua resposta não atende à pergunta porque a ideia é remover o `<br>` somente se estiver no final, por isso você ganhou votos negativos. Você pode corrigir sua pergunta para tentar ganhar votos positivos ou pode excluí-la para recuperar a pontuação perdida.