# Para que serve o "." (ponto) nas funções ltrim, rtrim e trim do PHP?

Tags: php, string

Eu estava aqui fazendo uma funcionalidade, onde eu precisava remover alguns caracteres do início de uma string, e não estava muito a fim de usar regex pra isso. Tentei utilizar a função `ltrim`, já que ela serve pra remover caracteres que estão à esquerda de uma string. Sempre usei ela pra remover prefixos.

O problema foi que acabei de descobrir que o caractere `.` serve como uma espécie de curinga.

No meu caso, eu tenho uma função que retorna o nome do arquivo utilizado no projeto, que sempre tem `.env.nome_do_cliente`. O problema surgiu quando quis pegar o nome do cliente baseando no nome desse arquivo.

Exemplificando

```
$nome_do_arquivo = '.env.exemplo';
$cliente = ltrim($nome_do_arquivo, '.env.');
// Resultado: "xemplo"
```

Exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0Z6PDa)

A minha intenção com o código acima era remover apenas o `.env.` da string. É claro que eu sei que tem como resolver isso com `substr` e ignorar até a quantidade de caracteres desejadas, porém o comportamento dessa função me deixou curioso. Fiquei na dúvida se era um comportamento esperado ou se era um bug.

Diante disso, tenho algumas perguntas:

- Se de fato o caractere `.` é interpretado como algo especial nessas funções, qual é a finalidade do mesmo nas funções `trim`, `ltrim` e `rtrim` ? Ou isso é um bug?
- Existe possibilidade de usar o caractere `.` como um caractere literal nas funções supracitadas? Por exemplo, utilizando `ltrim`, haveria alguma forma de remover apenas o caractere `.` do início de uma string? (Tentei usar `\.` e não deu certo).
- E, além do `.`, existem outros caracteres que podem ser interpretados como "curingas/especiais" por essa função?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23335

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade o segundo parâmetro contém a lista dos caracteres que serão removidos, e **não** é interpretado como uma substring. Exemplo:

```
echo ltrim('abcaabdef', 'cba'); // def
```

No exemplo acima, estou dizendo para remover qualquer caractere da "lista" `'cba'` - ou seja, ele percorre a string `'abcaabdef'` e vai removendo qualquer caractere que seja um "c", ou "b", ou "a". Quando encontra o primeiro que não é nenhum desta lista (no caso, o "d"), ele para e retorna dali em diante (ou seja, "def").

---

Sendo assim, ao usar `'.env.'` você está dizendo "remova um ponto, ou a letra `e`, ou `n`, ou `v`, ou um ponto". Por isso ele também remove o "e" antes do "x". E ao chegar no "x", ele para, pois "x" não é nenhum dos caracteres informados no segundo parâmetro.

Portanto o ponto não é interpretado como coringa. Tanto que se eu mudar a ordem dos caracteres, o resultado é o mesmo:

```
$nome_do_arquivo = '.env.exemplo';
$cliente = ltrim($nome_do_arquivo, 'vn.e');
echo $cliente; // xemplo
```

---

Só pra constar, o ponto pode ter significado especial se for usado assim:

```
echo ltrim('abcaabdef', 'a..d'); // ef
```

No caso, `a..d` significa "qualquer caractere entre `a` e `d`". Mas pelo que consta na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php), parece ser a única sintaxe especial, qualquer outra coisa é tratada como um caractere normal.

---

[`rtrim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) e [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) funcionam da mesma forma (o segundo parâmetro é tratado como uma lista de caracteres a serem removidos, não como uma substring), a diferença é que `rtrim` remove somente do final e `trim` remove do início e fim:

```
echo rtrim('abc123abcaab', 'cba'); // abc123
echo trim('abc123abcaab', 'cba'); // 123
echo ltrim('abc123abcaab', 'cba'); // 123abcaab
```

Comment: Tava na metade da minha resposta, mas você foi mais rápido. :P